# How can I prevent kill-visual-line from appending kills to the kill-ring?

Tags: kill-ring

As described in the manual, each kill command pushes a new entry onto the kill ring. However, two or more kill commands in a row combine their text into a single entry, so that a single C-y yanks all the text as a unit, just as it was before it was killed.

I don't want that;)

How can I prevent appending kills to the kill-ring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find a relevant user option, but you can implement it by executing the following code:

```lisp
(advice-add 'kill-visual-line :around
            (lambda (fn &rest args)
              (let (last-command)
                (apply fn args))))
```